# Unable add UIVIew to UITableView Cell Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a Card Based News feed (Similar to Facebook app) in iOS.I'm implementing programmatically because the height of UITablecell has to increase/decrease based on the data.

Consider i have one UIlabel and one UIImageView added, then the height of UITablecell should be  adjusted based on the fields. If one more text feild is added then height has to increase and if imageview is removed then height has to decrease.

The issue here is I couldn't  to add CustomView on the UItablecell programmatically but when i create using Interface builder then its working fine but the height remains constant which i don't want to have.

Can some one please help me out.

TableViewCell.h

```
   @interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

  @property (strong,nonatomic) UIView *customView;
  @property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *customLabel;
  @property (strong,nonatomic) UIImageView *customImage;


  @end
```

TableViewCell.m

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString            *)reuseIdentifier
  {
     self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
     if (self) {
    // configure control(s)

    [self addSubview:self.customView];
    [self.customView addSubview:self.customLabel];
    [self.customView addSubview:self.customImage];

 }
return self;
 }



  - (UIView *)customView
{
   if (!_customView)
   {
    _customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [_customView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
   }

   return _customView;

}


 - (UIImageView *)customImage
  {
     if (!_customImage)
    {
      _customImage = [UIImageView new];
      _customImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
      [_customImage.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
      [_customImage.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
      _customImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
      [_customImage setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  }

   return _customImage;
  }

 - (UILabel *)customLabel
 {
    if (!_customLabel)
    {
      _customLabel = [UILabel new];
      [_customLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    }

   return _customLabel;
}
```

UITableVIewController.m

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

   if (!_stubCell)
   {
      _stubCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"];
   }

   });

    CGFloat height =  [_stubCell.contentView   systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
   return height + 1;
  }

  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  return 50.f;
 }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

// Similar to UITableViewCell, but
_stubCell = (TableViewCell *)[theTableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (_stubCell == nil) {
    _stubCell = [[TableViewCell alloc]     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }

// Just want to test, so I hardcode the data
  _stubCell.customLabel.text = @"Testing";

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: You posted a bunch of code but you haven't explained your issue at all. Please update your question with a lot more detail about what you want, what is actually happening, and what you've figured out so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be better to create multiple nibs for the same class UITableViewCell, one for each of the possible layouts that you need. Depending on which nib is used then set heightForRowAtIndexPath to the height of the nib.

This will give you predictability of the layout for each situation and you connect only the fields defined in UITableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

never mind i found answer by myself. I am calculating the height of each UIView that is added the super view. Based on the total height the UITableview height increases and decrease and also using auto layout adjusting the layout constraints made me simple.

I am still working on the design once its done i'll post the code so that it will be help ful for other developers.